# nginx returns "Bad gateway - 502" on DigitalOcean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unix, nginx, unicorn

I am trying to configure nginx for a rails app on DigitalOcean. When I open my IP, I see the BAD GATEWAY (502) message.

In logs is

```
2014/06/03 09:58:57 [crit] 28612#0: *1 connect() to unix:/tmp/unicorn.myproject-staging.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 81.161.64.26, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.myproject-staging.sock:/500.html", host: "my_ip"
```

What does error message means and how could I fix it?

Thank you

**EDIT:**

The application is deployed here:

```
/home/deployer/apps/myproject-staging
```

Comment: How did you start your app/server? It isn't running on that sock as it seems.

Comment: Is your unicorn running ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check to ensure your Unicorn is running and the path to the unix socket file is right.

Comment: Thank you Tan for your answer. I am beginner in these server stuff, could you help me, please, how to ensure that Unicorn is running and the path to the unix socket is correct? I am using DigitalOcean - Ubuntu server. THank you